# How can I find customer by email in Shopify graphql

Tags: shopify-app, shopify-api

Now I am testing the Shopify graphql for get customer by email.
But Shopify Customer query does not work correctly. query is following.

```
    {
  customers(first: 10, query:"email:'test@gmail.com'") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        lastName
        verifiedEmail
        firstName
        lastName
        email
        phone
        tags 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but the result is following.

```
   {
  "data": {
    "customers": {
      "edges": []
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cost": {
      "requestedQueryCost": 252,
      "actualQueryCost": 2,
      "throttleStatus": {
        "maximumAvailable": 1000,
        "currentlyAvailable": 998,
        "restoreRate": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Shopify Store have that customer. But the query didn't find customer.
I am sure we can solve this problem.
If you have experience one, please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the token that you're using doesn't have permission to read `customer`. Can you check if your token has `read` permission to the `customers` object?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still need an answer. The string after query: needs to be just the email. see here:

```
query GetThat {
  customers(first: 10, query: "mikeyboy@aol.com"){
    edges{
      node {
        firstName
        lastName
        defaultAddress {
          id
          address1
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "data": {
    "customers": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "firstName": "MikeyBoy",
            "lastName": "ohohoh",
            "defaultAddress": {
              "id": "gid://shopify/MailingAddress/7969224163540?model_name=CustomerAddress",
              "address1": "123 sesame st"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cost": {
      "requestedQueryCost": 22,
      "actualQueryCost": 4,
      "throttleStatus": {
        "maximumAvailable": 1000,
        "currentlyAvailable": 996,
        "restoreRate": 50
      }
    }
  }
}
```